# How can I store custom facts about remote hosts in aggregate before proceeding with rest of the runbook?

Tags: ansible, ansible-facts

I'm writing a cluster provisioning playbook in Ansible that requires each node to be configured with the public certificates of the other nodes at installation time. I can't think of an easy way to tell ansible to:

1. Go fetch the remote certs
2. Shove them into a list
3. Make those cert summaries available to *each* remote node for generating the authorized list of nodes

At the moment, given the small amount of cluster-nodes, I'm going to do this by-hand (copy output of the first playbook into the variables of the second) but it would be most helpful if there was a way to do this in a single playbook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer will be as general as possible: storing a fact on a particular machine in a group and read that fact for all machines in group from an other machine.

1. I take for granted your playbook is actually targeting a group `my_node_group` containing all your cluster nodes.
2. Store an info from a remote node in its own facts (or get this directly from your inventory...).

   ```
   # This one should be replaced with getting certs in your context
   # with whatever solution is best suited for you.
   - name: Get an info from current machine
     shell: echo "I'm a dummy task running on {{ inventory_hostname }}" 
     register: my_info_cmd

   - name: Push info in a fact for current node
     set_fact:
       my_info: "{{ my_info_cmd.stdout }}"
   ```
3. This is the really usefull part: use the stored info elsewhere

   ```
   - name: example loop to access 'my_info` on each machines of group `my_node_group`
     debug:
       var: item
     loop: >-
       {{
         groups['my_node_group']
         | map('extract', hostvars, 'my_info')
         | list 
       }}
   ```

Explanation of last step

- Get machines in the group `my_node_group`
- Use those name to [map](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.10.x/templates/#map) the [`extract` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#extracting-values-from-containers) on `hostvars` and get a list of corresponding facts hashes where you only retain the `my_info` attribute
- Transform the returned map object to a list an loop over it.

Comment: thank you - this does help clarify a general strategy.  I'm concerned on concurrency for a large-host list: Is there anything that will force ansible to pause to ensure the gathering step has completed?

Comment: there is also the meta-problem of determining which group I'm currently executing against. I understand that a host can be in many groups, but only one group should be active?